# Where can I find what options that Route::resource supports?

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my `web.php` I have the following:

```php
    Route::resource('transactions/debit', 'TransactionController', [
        'except' => ['show', 'destroy'],
        'names' => [
            'index' => 'transactions.debit.index',
            'create' => 'transactions.debit.create',
            'store' => 'transactions.debit.store',
            'edit' => 'transactions.debit.edit',
            'update' => 'transactions.debit.update',
        ],
    ]);
```

I tried the Laravel reference, but the only thing it says is that `$options` is an array.

Where can I find what are all the `$options` that the `resource` method and others support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this where you need more information over what is available in the documentation, generally the next place to look is the code.

In this case, the class that handles `resource` routes is `ResourceRegistrar`. You can view the [code for the class here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResourceRegistrar.php).

For example, you can see the following usages in the class:

```
$ ag  "options\['.*?'\]" 
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResourceRegistrar.php

75:        if (isset($options['parameters']) && ! isset($this->parameters)) {
76:            $this->parameters = $options['parameters'];
157:        if (isset($options['only'])) {
158:            $methods = array_intersect($methods, (array) $options['only']);
161:        if (isset($options['except'])) {
162:            $methods = array_diff($methods, (array) $options['except']);
366:        if (isset($options['middleware'])) {
367:            $action['middleware'] = $options['middleware'];
388:        if (isset($options['names'])) {
389:            if (is_string($options['names'])) {
390:                $name = $options['names'];
391:            } elseif (isset($options['names'][$method])) {
392:                return $options['names'][$method];
399:        $prefix = isset($options['as']) ? $options['as'].'.' : '';
```

You can also see that the the options are passed to each individual route in the resource as well.